# Updating multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Using phpMyAdmin, I want to update multiple rows of data with some new information.

The 'uid' is unique to each record.
The 'pid' field is the same for all records.

I modified an INSERT INTO statment after I exported the data from another database.

```
UPDATE `tabme_name` SET (`uid`, `pid`, `title`, `category`) VALUES
(230952, 1902, 112, 27634),
(230953, 1902, 179, 27641),
(230954, 1902, 75, 27630),
(230955, 1902, 38, 27626);
```

I can only find information on updating one record, or updating records with the same information.
Could somebody show me a correct SQL Statment? I havn't got a WHERE clause in it!?!

Comment: What DBMS are you using? If you want to avoid emiting a single UPDATE for each ID, you might use some tricks but they're not standard ANSI SQL as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the uid is the pk you must execute multiple updates:

```
UPDATE tabme_name SET pid =  1902, title =112, category=27634 WHERE uid=230952
UPDATE tabme_name SET pid =  1902, title =179, category=27641 WHERE uid=230953
...
```

Comment: I guessed this answer... Wondered if there was another more efficient way to do it

Comment: In ANSI SQL it's the only way I believe.